# Will Universal Windows App run on windows phone 8 and windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I have a already existing app for windows phone 8 but now I want to make a universal app for the same so that it can run on both windows phone and windows 8. I read about this on internet a lot but still I am confused that if a make a universal windows app will it be able to run on windows phone 8 and windows 8 as the most of the tutorials are confusing as they talk only about windows phone 8.1 and windows 8.1. Can anyone please help me on this whether this is possible or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Universal app's is a new feature of Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1

They don't work on Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

No, Universal app for windows phone 8.1 and windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

There are Universal Apps for Windows 10 and Windows 8.1 but they are not compatible.

For further information: [Run Windows 10 Universal Apps on Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317848/run-windows-10-universal-apps-on-windows-8-1)