# Windows 10 Universal Apps backwards compatibility

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app

Will Windows 10 Universal Apps be backwards compatible and be able to run on Windows XP/7/8/8.1 ???
I assume it shouldn't be too difficult for Microsoft to run it in a windowed player that supports universal app api's.

Comment: Probably a better question somewhere else. http://superuser.com/ perhaps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Windows 10 Universal Apps on Windows 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317848/run-windows-10-universal-apps-on-windows-8-1)

Answer (score 7):

Currently they are not backwards compatible. And I wouldn't expect them to be - the goal is to move everyone from old Windows to the latest, Windows 10, so I assume that's where the focus will be.

Comment: That is correct -- no backwards compat. Win 10 Universal apps will only work on Win 10.

Comment: That's a good question and it seems to be targeting Win 10 onwards.