# convert 8.1 pro 64 bits to windows 10 is this a right choice to develop for UWP applications

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal

I need your help please,I want to develop for UWP with windows 10(I tried to install windows 10 as a VMWare workstation virtual machine but I never have found the right ISO file(my processor supports virtual machines of 32 bits),so I need to convert my windows 8.1 pro 64 bits to windows 10.

My question is, will this installation cause any errors:

This is my system configuration

Processor: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU P6200 @2.13Ghz 2.13Ghz

RAM: 4.00 Gb(3.80Gb used)

OS: 64bits,processor x64 Windows 8.1 Professional

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general OS tech support.

Comment: sorry Marc B for my question,I need just your help from your experience :)

Comment: thanks Sir Bear Armatis for the edit

Comment: You can ask these kinds of questions over at [superuser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Windows 10 Universal Apps on Windows 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317848/run-windows-10-universal-apps-on-windows-8-1)

Comment: make a full backup, so tat you can restore to Windows 8.1 if you have issues. There are a lot of free tools like Macrium Reflect Free: http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx

Comment: ok thanks magicandre1981 :)