# is it possible to develop a windows 8.1 app on windows 10?

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-8.1-universal

I need to develop a windows 8.1 app, is it possible to do on a Windows 10 PC?

I have a windows 8.1 device to test my app on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317848/run-windows-10-universal-apps-on-windows-8-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2015 to create Windows (Store) 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 apps.

[Download Visual Studio Community 2013](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=517284)

[Download Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs)

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to run windows 8.0 apps on windows 10?
I cant seem to find to find any concrete infomation on this.
The best I have is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317848/run-windows-10-universal-apps-on-windows-8-1

Comment: Yes, you can run Windows 8 apps on Windows 10

Comment: Does anyone know if I can develop 8.1 apps on Win 10 using Visual Studio 2017?