# Can Windows 10 UWP run on Windows 8.1 Devices?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

I'm building a Windows 10 UWP app, and would like to know if it will run on Windows Phone 8.1 and/or Windows 8.1 Desktop. Windows 8.1 is still quite prevalent, and I would like to be able to reach these users with my app.

Comment: It is impossible to create UWP app compatible with Windows 8.1/Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Windows 10 Universal Apps on Windows 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317848/run-windows-10-universal-apps-on-windows-8-1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows 10 apps can only run on Windows 10 (and newer). If you want to target 8.1, you have to build a 8.1. A 8.1 should run on Windows 10 without any problems.

Comment: Keep in mind that there are obscure differences between the platforms. You'll probably have to fully test and troubleshoot the app everywhere it is supposed to run. E.g. [StorageProvider.Id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storageprovider.id.aspx) of the files in OneDrive folder is "OneDrive" in Win 10, but "SkyDrive" in Win 8.1.