# How to create WP8.1 package from UWP project?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I heard we can create package for WP8.1 from UWP project if you haven't used any UWP specific codes? Just wanted to check how can we do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35054932/can-windows-10-uwp-run-on-windows-8-1-devices

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you can't create WP8.1 package from a UWP project. UWP apps have dependencies on Windows 10 Runtimes and compilation targets one or another version of Windows and corresponding SDKs.

What you can do is to use shared code between two projects. E.g. you can create a portable class library that will target both Windows Universal (10) and Windows Phone 8.1. There is also a [detailed article](https://nokiawpdev.wordpress.com/2015/05/27/one-xaml-for-uwp-windows-8-1-and-windows-phone-8-1/) by Lance McCarthy on how to use the same XAML for both UWP and WP8.1.