# how to use the API get_UserInteractionMode in universal app for windows 8?

Tags: win-universal-app

i need to know how to get the mode of device tablet or pc and can i do that 
using get_UserInteractionMode API in universal app,if yes then how ?

Comment: Do you want to develop an UWP app and run this app on windows 8? It's not possible. You can refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317848/run-windows-10-universal-apps-on-windows-8-1).

Comment: No, actually i have a 2 in 1 device whose screen is detachable , for that i want to create an windows app .I just want to identify which mode i am in .

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You say universal app and Windows 8, but Windows 8 does not support universal apps. Do you really mean Windows 10?