# Develop Universal apps for windows 10 from windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, windows-8.1, windows-10-universal

I have windows 8.1 and right now Visual Studio 2015 is installing on my machine. Can I develop universal windows apps UWA for windows 10 from my windows 8.1 ? 
If worth mentioning, I have another machine with windows 10 at home, and I think I read somewhere before I can use the other machine remotely to test my apps but I have been looking without finding how to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317848/run-windows-10-universal-apps-on-windows-8-1

Comment: Yeah, you are right. You can develop Universal Windows apps with Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 8.1 and test them on a remote Windows 10 device. However for developing Windows Universal Apps, Windows 10 is strongly recommended. For more info, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. [You need Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/get-set-up) to develop Windows 10 UWP apps.

> **1. Get Windows 10**
>
> To develop UWP apps, you need the latest version of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this is possible. We can develop Universal Windows apps with Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 8.1 and test them on a remote Windows 10 device.

For more info, please see **[Requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx#Anchor_0)** in [Develop apps for the Universal Windows Platform (UWP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx)

> **Windows 8.1 and Windows 7 support**
>
> If you choose to develop Universal Windows apps with Visual Studio 2015 on a platform other than Windows 10, these are the restrictions:
>
> - Windows 8.1: You can’t run the app locally (only on a remote Windows 10 device). You can use the emulators in Visual Studio, but not the simulator.
> - Windows 7: You can’t run the app locally (only on a remote Windows 10 device). You can’t use the emulators or the simulator in Visual Studio either.

And for test on remote devices, please see [**Specifying a remote device**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps#specifying-a-remote-device) in [Deploying and debugging Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps).

However, when using OS earlier than Windows 10, some Visual Studio features for Windows Universal development may be degraded, such as you can't use the XAML designer on Windows 8.1:
[image]

For a better experience of developing Windows Universal Apps, **Windows 10 is strongly recommended**.

Comment: ok, if it works, you should request an update of the documentation

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for your feedback. Although we can use Windows 8.1 to develop UWP apps, we still need Windows 10 devices for testing. The Get started document is a instruction for those who are new to UWP apps. It suggest them use Windows 10 for better experiences. For the requirements of developing UWP apps, please refer to the [Requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx#Anchor_0) in MSDN. :)