# UWP MediaPlayerElement Backwards Compatibility

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

So I am hoping this will be an easy solution. I am currently designing a media app that uses a  `MediaPlayerElement`. I am developing on Windows 14393 (Anniversary Update) I have read that the `MediaPlaerElement` is only supported in this version but I would like to support older versions of Windows (Build 10586 or 10240) as well. What would be the best way to do this? I have started in my code below but don't know what I should use to display the video in older versions.

Creation Code in frame constructor:

```
        if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract", 3))
        {
            MediaPlayerElement newPlayer = new MediaPlayerElement()
            {
                AreTransportControlsEnabled = true,
                Stretch = Stretch.Uniform,
                AutoPlay = true,
                IsRightTapEnabled = false
            };
            newPlayer.TransportControls.IsZoomButtonVisible = false;
            newPlayer.TransportControls.IsZoomButtonVisible = false;
            Player = newPlayer.MediaPlayer;
            newPlayer.TransportControls.DoubleTapped += SingleMediaElement_DoubleTapped;
            this.MainGrid.Children.Add(newPlayer);
        }
        else
        {
            //Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer oldPLayer = new Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer()
            //{
            //    AutoPlay = true
            //};
        }
```

What would be the best way to create and use a video player in my app on older versions of windows (ideally UniversalAPI 1.0)?

Thanks!!

Comment: You [can't run universal apps on earlier versions of Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317848/run-windows-10-universal-apps-on-windows-8-1)

Comment: Sorry, I meant like version 5011 or original release of Windows 10, updating question

Comment: [MediaElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242926)?

Comment: Should I just make a MediaElement in the else statement and add it to the frame like I did the MediaPlayerElement? I access multiple parts of the MediaPlayer in other parts of the program (source, volume, etc.). Will I need to handle doing these differently each time I want to use them then?

Comment: I know MediaPlayer was available in all versions of Windows 10. Is there any way to show a MediaPlayer on a UI before MediaPlayerElement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the best way to create and use a video player in my app on older versions of windows (ideally UniversalAPI 1.0)?

Using a MediaElement:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="me" Source="ms-appx:///video.wmv" AutoPlay="True" />
```

**MediaElement class:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aspx

Comment: Thank you! I will implement this for the case of MediaPlayerElement not existing